# See mypy type of what's under point

Tags: python

Is it possible to see mypy types in emacs?  I would like a command that does something like show the type of what's under point (presumably getting that information from the mypy cache for speed?).  Or alternatively, I might be happy with a UI like lsp-mode's (perhaps using lsp-mode itself) that shows the type immediately when point is over something, without needing to run a command.

Would be interested to know also if there is an easy way to set things up in spacemacs, but this question is primarily about the generic emacs issue.

Comment: I recall the main thing preventing this some months back is lack of support for this from mypy itself (but, again from memory, I think they do want to provide support for it eventually). Types in e.g. VS code I believe come from proprietary Microsoft code whose source either isn't published or is published under a non-free license.  Perhaps the necessary information is there in the mypy cache for a sufficiently determined implementor though?  :-)

Comment: Support seems to be there in mypy now (in the form of experimental support from mypy 0.981 on, in dmypy in particular) https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mypy_daemon.html#statically-inspect-expressions I'm still surprised by how few requests this feature this seems to get from emacs users.  Does that mean that emacs support exists for this dmypy feature now, somewhere I haven't noticed it?  Perhaps in https://github.com/python-lsp/pylsp-mypy ?